# cities' sizes vs cities' size

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

> The government should extend **cities’ sizes** by providing the infrastructure required for this expansion.

Should I make it cities' size?

> The government should extend **cities’ size** by providing the infrastructure required for this expansion.

I am confused because a city has one size, however, the government will expand the size(s) of multiple cities.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use "the size of cities", if for no other reason than to avoid a plural possessive. They get annoying.

With the "Saxon genitive" *-'s* (or just *-'* in this case), I think *sizes* should be plural. It works better as singular when using *of*, though.